# Starting Script on Server when QR-Code gets scanned

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, qr-code

is it possible to let a web server, for example my Raspberry Pi, start a Script when a specific QR-Code gets scanned from my Mobile Device connected to my Home-Network?
e.x.: I want the Pi to delete spezific data from a Database if the QR-Code gets scanned from a Mobile Device inside my Network.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, QR codes aren't magic.  All they contain is a string of text.  That text could say "Hello", or be a phone number, email address, or URL.

It is up to the QR scanner to decide what to do with the text it encounters.

For example, you could build a QR scanner which tells your Pi to delete data when it scans the text "123abc".

Or, you could have a URL like `http://192.168.0.34/delete?data=abc123` where the IP address is the internal network address of your Pi.